# Why does my for loop sometimes execute twice, despite my use of a break statement?

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, break

In the code below, the first if-statement inside the for loop sometimes fires twice. It logs "hello" twice, and the same SMS is send twice, despite of the break-statement. What's wierd is that it only happens about 30% of the time. Any help is appreciated.

```
for (let indexS = prisData.length - 1; -1 < indexS; indexS--) {
        if (prisData[indexS].købt === true && prisData[indexS].købtFor < købsPrisNu - netto) {
            solgtFor = købsPrisNu
            solgt = true
            console.log("hello");
            nexmo.message.sendSms(from, to, 'Sælg wirtek til ' + solgtFor, {type : 'text'},(err, data) => {if (err != null) {console.log(err)}})
            break
        }
        if (prisData[indexS].solgt === true) {
            break
        }
    }
```

Comment: Put a `console.log("for loop starts")` just before the `for` line. It seems the only way hello is printed twice is by the for loop being executing twice.

Comment: Can you share the values of a few more variables. Its very hard to replicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me simplify this code for you:

```
function foo()
{
    for ([...]) {
            if (...) {
                [...]
                console.log("hello");
                sendSms();
                break
            }
              [...]
        }
}
```

Regardless of what is in the [...] parts, the `console.log("hello")` statement cannot be called twice for one call of foo().

The only reasonable possibility for the log statement being executed more than once is if the function is called multiple times or if it calls itself (e.g. sendSms() calls foo() directly or indirectly).